# Equivariant bilinear form on irreducible representation must be symmetric or skew-symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, bilinear-form, characters

Let $V$ be an irreducible complex representation of a finite group $G$ with character $\chi$. Then the dual $V^*$ is also a $G$-representation via $(g\cdot \ell)(v) = \ell(g^{-1}v)$, and its character can be easily computed as $\overline{\chi}$. From here we easily get that since $V$ is irreducible, so is $V^*$ (by computing the inner product).

Assume $\beta: V\times V\to \mathbb{C}$ is a nonzero equivariant bilinear form, where equivariant means $\beta(gx,gy)=\beta(x,y)$ for any $g\in G, x,y\in V$. This can be interpreted as a map $\varphi: V\to V^*$ sending $v\mapsto \beta(v,-)$, and in fact $\varphi$ is a map of $G$-representations. Hence by Schur's Lemma it is an isomorphism and so $V\cong V^*$ as $G$-representations. Comparing characters this implies $\chi$ is real-valued.

My goal is to prove that this implies that either $\beta$ is symmetric or skew-symmetric; i.e. $\beta(x,y)=\beta(y,x)$ for all $x,y\in V$; or $\beta(x,y)=-\beta(y,x)$ for all $x,y\in V$. Would anyone have insights on how to prove this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V^*\otimes V^*$ decomposes as a representation of $G$ into the direct sum of $\Lambda^2(V^*)$ and $Sym^2(V^*)$, so since you have at most one copy of the trivial representation in $V^*\otimes V^*$, it must live in one of these pieces, which correspond to alternating or symmetric forms respectively.

Comment: Wow what an elegant approach, you're right! $\beta$ as an element of the $G$-representation $V^* \otimes V^*$, must actually satisfy $g\beta=\beta$ so it lies inside a copy of the trivial rep. Computing the character of this representation gives that it contains only one copy of the trivial rep and so we finish by what you said. Thank you!